# Wellingtonia and disturbing roots

Tags: trees

Can you please help.  I have two Wellingtonia (I think that is right) in my garden.  One is around 195ft and the other slightly smaller.  There is a wooded area around 10 metres away and I believe they are trying to offer this up for development.  Would this cause my tree roots damage.

Regards

Hilary

Comment: Could you tell us what country and county you are in?  Laws and protection vary a great deal. The UK has much better tree protections law than let’s say the USA.  Also, don’t let the construction fold drive or park under the trees the wheel of ANY vehicles will damage the roots.

Comment: @CloneZero If they start parking vehicles in someone's garden without permission, you have more cause for complaint than just damaging some tree roots!

Comment: There should be some regulations preventing building anything bigger than a dog kennel 30 feet away from a 195 foot tree anyway. If this was in the UK you would automatically get a copy of the plans for any proposed building work next to your own property and there is a procedure to raise objections before the plans are approved, but the law in other countries may be different of course.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer here is "Yes". In general, any heavy equipment parked under the dripline (that would be the radius of the canopy multiplied by 1.5) will compact the soil and harm the roots' ability to take up oxygen and water. The heavier the equipment, the number of times it's parked on the roots, and the moisture in the soil when parked will all affect the tree. Of course, if they'll be doing any trenching within 10m of the trunk then they could actually kill the tree.

A possibly useful resource:
https://www.planningni.gov.uk/downloads/best-practice-trees-2.pdf

At the very least, I recommend getting some steel fencepoles and temporary fencing and putting a fence on your property line so that the developers can't easily park/work on your side of the line.

Best of luck to you!